# SQL - Transfer values between tables in nested queries

Tags: sql, sql-server

A python faithful here trying to get things done with SQL queries instead of Pandas. This is probably a pretty basic question but here goes:

So I have a table called Reading which shows monthly electricity usage for different locations:

```
=== Reading ===
ID  PlacementID DateFrom    DateUntil   Usage
1   3552        2018-07-01  2018-07-31  5992
2   3552        2018-08-01  2018-08-31  6318
3   3554        2018-08-01  2018-08-31  4782
4   3554        2018-09-01  2018-09-30  2001
5   3558        2018-08-01  2018-08-31  1582
6   3558        2018-09-01  2018-09-30  1825
```

I also have a table called ReadingDay which stores daily usage values in a similar way - however, it doesn't contain PlacementID - instead it relates to the Reading table through a column called "ReadingID" which corresponds to the "ID" column in Reading:

```
=== ReadingDay ===
ID  ReadingID   Date        Usage
1       1       2018-07-01  302
2       1       2018-07-02  254
....
182     6       2018-09-30  186
183     6       2018-09-31  104
```

What I am aiming to do in this case is query the ReadingDay table for all instances belong to PlacementID 3552 and 3558 as declared in the Reading table, and also create a column called "PlacementID" in the ReadingDay table so that one can easily see which location is referenced in the data without having to look at the Reading table.

This is my non-functional newbie code trying to do (The reasons why this doesn't work is obvious even to me but it's my best take so far):

```
SELECT ID, ReadingID, Date, Usage 
FROM ReadingDay
WHERE ReadingID IN (
    SELECT ID
    FROM Reading
    WHERE PlacementID IN (3552, 3558)
)
INSERT PlacementID
```

Comment: Hint:  `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: Ah, yes of course! Thank you!

Comment: You seem to be engaging in a process of actively reducing the normalisation of your database. This is unwise

Comment: Haha, this is just a query request, I just formulated myself incorrectly with the "creating a column" term - that's just for the query, not for restructuring the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

select rd.ID, rd.ReadingID, rd.Date, rd.Usage, r.PlacementID
from ReadingDay rd 
inner join 
Reading r 
on rd.ID = r.PlacementID

WHERE r.PlacementID IN (3552, 3558)

Comment: Exactly what I'm looking for! Thanks :)